# Can't get shared files / folder shared by others with me

Tags: onedrive

Using the new OneDrive for Android, I was unable to get files / folder shared with me by others, by using new uri

```
/drive/shared
```

The uri `/drive/shared` is showing the files / folder that are shared by me to others

Comment: i m using the new onedrive api https://api.onedrive.com/v1.0

Answer (score 0):

The API doesn't yet expose items shared with you, but this is something we're working on.

Comment: and ty for ur help...
Till what time do you think it will be available for using???

Answer (score 0):

Info on shared items is crucial for my app too. If we can get a tentative time frame on this feature's availability, that would be useful.